# Count length of images in a string

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am trying to get length of images in a string.

My string

```
$page="<img><img><img><img>";
```

From the string above ,I want to get the output "4 images".

I tried `preg_match_all()` and `count()` function, but it always returns "1 images".

```
$page="<img><img><img><img>";
preg_match_all("/<img>/",$page,$m);
echo count($m);
```

Is there any other way to know how much images are in a string?

Comment: If it is a fixed value, you can use `substr_count()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Preg_match_all` returns a multidimensional array. The arrays are the capture groups. Since you aren't capturing anything you want to count the `0` index of `$m` (which is all found values). So use:

```
echo count($m[0]);
```

For demonstration this is your `$m`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img>
            [1] => <img>
            [2] => <img>
            [3] => <img>
        )

)
```

The `count` only counts the `0` index, so you get `1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use code

```
<?php
$page="<img><img><img><img>";
preg_match_all("/<img>/",$page,$m);
echo count($m[0]);
?>
```

Or this is the alternative

```
<?php
$page="<img><img><img><img>";
$words = substr_count($page, '<img>');
print_r($words);
?>
```